# Dicontinuities of Dirichlet function.

Tags: real-analysis

We know that the Dirichlet function are not continuous everywhere. But what about the number of discontinuities? are they countable or uncountable?

Comment: It's discontinuous at every point.

Comment: uncountable i.e cardinality of $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Dirichlet function had countably many discontinuities, then the set of discontinuities would have measure zero and hence would be Riemann integrable by Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integration. However, the Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable, so we can conclude that there are uncountably many discontinuities. In fact, this function is discontinuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$.